# Fermentation growing too fast for bin

Tags: fermentation, cider, equipment

I started fermenting my first batch of turbo cider yesterday (10/07/2022). I'm using this [this 5L fermentation bucket](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B003E14DXC/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) but the foam has already creeping up to the lid. It's very hot in England right now, which is speeding up the brewing process.

With the foam at the level it is only after 24 hours, I really think I need to pour my fermenting cider into a larger bin.

Will this cause harm to the brew? Should I do something else instead, like just scrape the foam off?

My brew consists of:

- 4L of apple juice
- 2.5g ale yeast
- 1tsp yeast nutrient
- 1 mug of tea
- 300g sugar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, at this early stage it won't cause any harm. Just a more risk of contamination..but cider ferments out pretty dry so it's a little safer. Though by the time you've poured it, the bulk of the most vigorous fermentation will likely already be complete.

However for the sake of simplicity I'd really just recommend using a blow-off tube.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll go by what you say and leave it be. By the time I do the next batch I'll get a blow-off tube :)